# generics error : duplicate type parameter

Tags: java, generics

This is what my code looks like

```
public interface Initializer<A, B> {

    public B init(A input);
}

public abstract class AbstractInitializer<A, B> implements Initializer<A, B> {

    private B output;

    @Override
    public final B init(A input) {
        if (output != null)
            return output;
        return initialize(input);
    }

    protected abstract B initialize(A input);
}

public class MemoryInitializer<Map, Map> extends AbstractInitializer<Map, Map> {

    @Override
    protected Map initialize(Map input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

the final concrete implementation,where I expect input to be map and output to be a map after initialization, throws a compiler error that says, **"Duplicate type parameter Map"**. What am I missing?

Comment: why the downvote to close?! man, SO is becoming a place where we have people racing to downvote questions with no logical explanation. I feel very sad about this.

Comment: You're declaring MemoryInitializer as generic, with two type parameters, Map and... Map.  I don't think you intend for MemoryInitializer to be itself generic.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom yes, got it. Fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is used when you want to allow generics within your class

```
MemoryInitializer<Map, Map>
```

---

To be clearer, if you used

```
MyClass<T, T>
```

It would have throw the same error.

You have to use different names for your generics in the class signature

```
MyClass<T, U>
```

Comment: so, it is giving me an error because I declared the interface as two different types, A and B, but ended up creating an implementation of same type. But, you are also saying even if I create the interface with two types A,A (which ofcourse makes no sense, would rather just use one A), even then it would give the same error. Interesting.

Comment: I did something like this MemoryInitializer<Map,HashMap> .. that still worked.

Comment: @Jay Of course but your mistake is thinking that the names of your generices `Map` and `HashMap` will be perceived by the system like the collections.

Comment: valid point. so, to make the system think that they are not "labels" but actual collections, what should I do?

Comment: @Jay You'd have to change that when you implement your class within your code logic. Take the example for ArrayList. The class is coded like `ArrayList<T>` but when you use it, you tend to reference the object type directly like `ArrayList<String>` for example. Or `ArrayList<Map>` in your case :)

Comment: ok, I did this - MemoryInitializer extends AbstractInitializer<Map, Map>. I see what I was doing wrong now. MemoryInitializer is a concrete implementation, there was no point in adding generic to it.